# 18.10 upgrade from 18.04 -- Login loop. Can't mount private data

Tags: mount, login, encryption, ecryptfs

Upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10.  All worked well until I shut down.  Now when I boot up, I get the login loop.  Enter passphrase and go back to main login screen.

I did the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and find that my /home/steve folder contains only one directory and 4 linked files.

I also see just after the command line login the message "mount: Bad address"

I tried `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`  It found /home/.ecryptfs/steve/.Private

I entered the login passphrase and see this series of messages:

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [193135fb7689a807] into user session keyring
mount: /tmp/ecryptfs.skNK9k22: mount(2) system call failed: Bad adderss.  
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.skNK9k22]
```

That directory does exist in /tmp with privs drwk------ for root root

folder ecryhptfs.skNK9k22 contains only the . and .. directories.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the passphrase is correct, since the recovery script "Inserted auth tok with sig [193135fb7689a807] into user session keyring" OK.

There's few results now when searching for *mount (2) "system call failed: bad address"*, but [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1798769) involves upgrading from 18.04.1 to 18.10 also, and [a thread on Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2404040&page=2&s=32648c22e941e7ebcf1bae10d79f5491) and they can't seem to mount anything even in a terminal. If you're not able to mount anything either, it's looking like a bug in the upgrade somehow, or at least something wrong with the upgrade & eCryptfs.

To recover (or at least backup) your home files, I would:

1. Boot a live ISO of Ubuntu 18.04 (but trying a live 18.10 might work too, in case it's only an upgrade related problem)
2. Run `ecryptfs-recover-private` on your mounted home partition, mounting/decrypting your home files
3. Copy/backup your files so they're at least safe

Then, in your main 18.10 install, I'd try creating a new user with an encrypted home, verify that they can log out & in successfully, and delete & re-create your main user & copy your backed up home files to your new home.

Comment: I now have a live ISO of 18.04 running.  Had to install ecryptfs-utils and now step 2 can't find a directory to decrypt.  Researching to see if I can point it to the mount point on /media

Comment: It should be on your old home partition, as long as it's mounted and readable (probably have to run the recover-private program as root iirc). I think it's in home/.ecryptfs/username, not the home/username (that gets used when it's decrypted/mounted normally)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'login' from the root shell? I believe I am experiencing the same issue, or at least the same symptoms, and was able to login from the root shell to access my user data decrypted.

Comment: That also gave me a "bad address" for the mount.  After poking at it with the 18.04 live ISO, finally told me that it was configured wrong.  I gave up and am rebuilding the box.  The user folder was backed up to Windows -- now to just get it all hooked up again!